# Adaptive algorithms implementation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have worked with kmeans and would like to use adaptive methods.
Do you know any library or a way to do that in OpenCV?

Comment: adaptive methods for what? clustering? something different? how is k-means relevant for all of that? please elaborate your question, there are adaptive algorithms for a wide range of uses. what are you trying to achieve? don't expect good answers if you don't write a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the function k-nearest neighbor in OpenCV. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
#include "ml.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    const int K = 10;
    int i, j, k, accuracy;
    float response;
    int train_sample_count = 100;
    CvRNG rng_state = cvRNG(-1);
    CvMat* trainData = cvCreateMat( train_sample_count, 2, CV_32FC1 );
    CvMat* trainClasses = cvCreateMat( train_sample_count, 1, CV_32FC1 );
    IplImage* img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 500, 500 ), 8, 3 );
    float _sample[2];
    CvMat sample = cvMat( 1, 2, CV_32FC1, _sample );
    cvZero( img );

    CvMat trainData1, trainData2, trainClasses1, trainClasses2;

    // form the training samples
    cvGetRows( trainData, &trainData1, 0, train_sample_count/2 );
    cvRandArr( &rng_state, &trainData1, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(200,200), cvScalar(50,50) );

    cvGetRows( trainData, &trainData2, train_sample_count/2, train_sample_count );
    cvRandArr( &rng_state, &trainData2, CV_RAND_NORMAL, cvScalar(300,300), cvScalar(50,50) );

    cvGetRows( trainClasses, &trainClasses1, 0, train_sample_count/2 );
    cvSet( &trainClasses1, cvScalar(1) );

    cvGetRows( trainClasses, &trainClasses2, train_sample_count/2, train_sample_count );
    cvSet( &trainClasses2, cvScalar(2) );

    // learn classifier
    CvKNearest knn( trainData, trainClasses, 0, false, K );
    CvMat* nearests = cvCreateMat( 1, K, CV_32FC1);

    for( i = 0; i < img->height; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < img->width; j++ )
        {
            sample.data.fl[0] = (float)j;
            sample.data.fl[1] = (float)i;

            // estimates the response and get the neighbors' labels
            response = knn.find_nearest(&sample,K,0,0,nearests,0);

            // compute the number of neighbors representing the majority
            for( k = 0, accuracy = 0; k < K; k++ )
            {
                if( nearests->data.fl[k] == response)
                    accuracy++;
            }
            // highlight the pixel depending on the accuracy (or confidence)
            cvSet2D( img, i, j, response == 1 ?
                (accuracy > 5 ? CV_RGB(180,0,0) : CV_RGB(180,120,0)) :
                (accuracy > 5 ? CV_RGB(0,180,0) : CV_RGB(120,120,0)) );
        }
    }

    // display the original training samples
    for( i = 0; i < train_sample_count/2; i++ )
    {
        CvPoint pt;
        pt.x = cvRound(trainData1.data.fl[i*2]);
        pt.y = cvRound(trainData1.data.fl[i*2+1]);
        cvCircle( img, pt, 2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), CV_FILLED );
        pt.x = cvRound(trainData2.data.fl[i*2]);
        pt.y = cvRound(trainData2.data.fl[i*2+1]);
        cvCircle( img, pt, 2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), CV_FILLED );
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "classifier result", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "classifier result", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvReleaseMat( &trainClasses );
    cvReleaseMat( &trainData );
    return 0;
}
```

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/k_nearest_neighbors.html

If you want to use this in c++ there is a great tutorial on this website:

http://aishack.in/tutorials/knearest-neighbors-in-opencv/